# Use TPL Dataflow to encapsulate pipeline ending in an action block

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

TPL Dataflow provides a very useful function:

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput> Encapsulate<TInput, TOutput>(
    ITargetBlock<TInput> target, 
    ISourceBlock<TOutput> source)
```

to enable you to, well, encapsulate multiple blocks into a single transform block. It returns a

```
IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
```

which represents the start and end blocks of your pipeline.

However, if the last block in my pipeline is an ActionBlock, I can't use this, since an ActionBlock is not a SourceBlock, and the return type of the function would be an ITargetBlock, not an IPropagatorBlock.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is something like this function:

```
public static ITargetBlock<TStart> Encapsulate<TStart, TEnd>(
        ITargetBlock<TStart> startBlock, 
        ActionBlock<TEnd> endBlock)
```

Is this a sensible thing to write, or am I missing something simple? I'm not quite sure how *to* write it - particularly wiring up the completion. Would I need to create my own custom block type?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so having read the response from @Panagiotis Kanavos, and done some tinkering, I've come up with this. This is based on the EncapsulatingPropagator class, which is what the existing DataflowBlock.Encapsulate method uses:

```
internal sealed class EncapsulatingTarget<TStart, TEnd> : ITargetBlock<TStart>
{
        private readonly ITargetBlock<TStart> startBlock;

        private readonly ActionBlock<TEnd> endBlock;

        public EncapsulatingTarget(ITargetBlock<TStart> startBlock, ActionBlock<TEnd> endBlock)
        {
            this.startBlock = startBlock;
            this.endBlock = endBlock;
        }

        public Task Completion
        {
            get { return this.endBlock.Completion; }
        }

        public void Complete()
        {
            this.startBlock.Complete();
        }

        void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception exception)
        {
            if (exception == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");
            }

            this.startBlock.Fault(exception);
        }

        public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(
            DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, 
            TStart messageValue, 
            ISourceBlock<TStart> source, 
            bool consumeToAccept)
        {
            return this.startBlock.OfferMessage(messageHeader, messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And I just finished posting a similar update! Nice job on making this generic - this allows you to separate building the module/fragment from the boilerplate

Comment: Being able to treat a "terminating" pipeline's initial target and completions as a single ActionBlock-like entity seems so obvious a need that the gap in API almost feels... purposeful. But I'll whistle past the graveyard and use your work here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encapsulate isn't used to abstract an existing pipeline, it's used to create a *propagator* block that requires custom behaviour that can't be implemented using the existing blocks and links.

For example, the [Sliding Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228606(v=vs.110).aspx) sample buffers all incoming messages posted to its input block and outputs a batch of all retrieved messages when a sliding window expires to its output block.

The names of the method create a lot of confusion but they do make sense when you understand their purpose:

- The *target* argument is the target (input) endpoint to which *preceding* blocks will connect to send messages. In this case, an ActionBlock that processes incoming messages and decides whether or not to post to the output (source) block makes sense.
- The *source* argument is the source (output) endpoint to which *succeeding* steps will connect to receive messages. It doesn't make sense to use an ActionBlock as a source because it *doesn't* have any output.

An `Encapsulate` variant that accepts an ActionBlock method as `source` isn't useful because you can simply link from any previous step to an action block.

**EDIT**

If you want to *modularize* a pipeline, ie break it into reuseable, more manageable  you can create a class that construct, you can use a plain old class. In that class, you build your pipeline fragment as normal, link the blocks (ensuring completion is propagated) and then expose the first step and the Completion task of the last step as public properties, eg:

```
class MyFragment
{
    public TransformationBlock<SomeMessage,SomeOther> Input {get;}

    public Task Completion {get;}

    ActionBlock<SomeOther> _finalBlock;

    public MyFragment()
    {
        Input=new TransformationBlock<SomeMessage,SomeOther>(MyFunction);
        _finalBlock=new ActionBlock<SomeOther>(MyMethod);
        var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true}
        Input.LinkTo(_finalBlock,linkOptions);
    }

    private SomeOther MyFunction(SomeMessage msg)
    {
    ...
    }

    private void MyMethod(SomeOther msg)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

To connect the fragment to a pipeline, you only need to link from a pipeline block to the exposed `Input` block. To await completion, just await on the exposed `Completion` task.

You could stop here if you want, or you can implement [ITargetBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194833(v=vs.110).aspx) to make the fragment look like a Target block. You just need to delegate all methods to the Input block and the Completion property to the final block.

Eg:

```
class MyFragment:ITargetBlock<SomeMessage> 
{
    ....

    public Task Completion {get;}

    public void Complete()
    {
        Input.Complete()
    };

    public void Fault(Exception exc)
    {
        Input.Fault(exc);
    }

    DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader,
        TInput messageValue,ISourceBlock<TInput> source,bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        return Input.OfferMessage(messageHeader,messageValue,source,consumeToAccept);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Using @bornfromanegg 's class one can separate the act of building the fragment from the boilerplate that exposes the Input and Completion:

```
public ITargetBlock<SomeMessage> BuildMyFragment()
{
    var input=new TransformationBlock<SomeMessage,SomeOther>(MyFunction);
    var step2=new TransformationBlock<SomeOther,SomeFinal>(MyFunction2);
    var finalBlock=new ActionBlock<SomeFinal>(MyMethod);

    var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true}

    input.LinkTo(step2,linkOptions);
    step2.LinkTo(finalBlock,linkOptions);

    return new EncapsulatingTarget(input,finalBlock);
}
```

Comment: I agree up to a point. In fact, not only does it not make sense to use ActionBlock as a source - it's not *possible* to use it as a source because it does not implement ISourceBlock. But I still have a problem to solve: I have a pipeline where the last block is an action block, and I want to encapsulate it.

Comment: The `Encapsulate` method has a very specific (and limited) purpose - it's not a generic encapsulation mechanism. It is useful when you need to include a complex graph or code with well defined input and output endpoints in a pipeline. It's a shortcut to implementing your own block class.  In your case, you only need a link from the rest of the pipeline to your first block and awaiting on the Completion task of the last block - just as you would with any pipeline. You can even include the blocks in a class, exposing the input block and the ActionBlock's Completion tasks as properties.

Comment: I think what you actually mean here is to *modularize*, not encapsulate a pipeline.

Comment: Yes, that is perhaps what I mean. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Splendid - that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wanted to encapsulate a network that comprised multiple final `ActionBlock`s, with a summarized completion, so the solution outlined in the edited question didn't work.

Because the only interaction with the "final block" surrounds completion, it suffices to present just the completion task for the encapsulation. (Added target-action constructor per suggestion.)

```
public class EncapsulatingTarget<TInput> : ITargetBlock<TInput>
{
    private readonly ITargetBlock<TInput> startBlock;

    private readonly Task completion;

    public EncapsulatingTarget(ITargetBlock<TInput> startBlock, Task completion)
    {
        this.startBlock = startBlock;
        this.completion = completion;
    }

    public EncapsulatingTarget(ITargetBlock<TStart> startBlock, ActionBlock<TEnd> endBlock)
    {
        this.startBlock = startBlock;
        completion = endBlock.Completion;
    }

    public Task Completion => completion;

    public void Complete()
    {
        startBlock.Complete();
    }

    void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");
        }

        startBlock.Fault(exception);
    }

    public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(
        DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader,
        TInput messageValue,
        ISourceBlock<TInput> source,
        bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        return startBlock.OfferMessage(messageHeader, messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
public ITargetBlock<Client.InputRecord> BuildDefaultFinalActions()
{
    var splitter = new BroadcastBlock<Client.InputRecord>(null);
    var getresults = new TransformManyBlock(...);    // propagator
    var saveinput = new ActionBlock(...);
    var saveresults = new ActionBlock(...);

    splitter.LinkTo(saveinput, PropagateCompletion);
    splitter.LinkTo(getresults, PropagateCompletion);
    getresults.LinkTo(saveresults, PropagateCompletion);

    return new Util.EncapsulatedTarget<Client.InputRecord>(splitter, Task.WhenAll(saveinput.Completion, saveresults.Completion));
}
```

I could have made the signature `EncapsulatingTarget<T>(ITargetBlock<T> target, params Task[] completions)` and moved the `WhenAll(...)` inside the constructor, but didn't want to make assumptions about desired completion notification.

Comment: This looks like a useful addition. In fact, I see no reason why you couldn't have _both_ those constructors, as well as the original which takes an `ActionBlock`. That way you give the caller the choice as to which to use.